# Getting list of apps from iCloud

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, icloud, icloud-api

Is there any way to get a list of apps in iCloud programmatically? I need to get a list of apps only.

Comment: Apps that I own and are present in my iCloud.

Answer (score 0):

No, Apple's sandboxing would prevent you from accessing the list of iCloud-enabled apps the user has installed.

Comment: So you mean there is no way to see the apps you own; programmatically?